# How to detect if barcode scanner is attached to PC

Tags: c#, windows, barcode-scanner

I am writing an application which detects if any bar-code scanner is attached to the pc or not. I don't know how to query the installed devices to check for barcode scanners. I am using C# and .NET 4.0.

Comment: What type of barcode scanners. It would be extremely difficult if it should be for all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some barcode scanner are attached by keyboard wedge (Or their drivers report them as keyboards) - I believe there is no way to test if these are present.

Other specific scanners may be accessible through their USB ports but any status query will have to be on a model by model basis.

Answer (score 1):

You probably want to use WMI...

Heres some CodeProject links that might help.

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/18268/How-To-Almost-Everything-In-WMI-via-C-Part-3-Hardw

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/21503/Hardware-Helper-Library-for-C

Comment: I know abt WMI and its capability. But what i want to know is , Is there some kind of standard attributes of a device by whom I can detect if it is a barcode scanner or not. I am trying to avoid harcoding the models in my application.

Comment: I doubt it...too many different types. Even if you detect a device is a Barcode Scanner, you may not have a common interface to interact with it.